# The problem of adapting the MSVC++ code for C++Builder- __declspec(align(n))

Tags: visual-c++, alignment, c++builder

I have a huge issue of adapting the code into C++Builder.

What is the equivalent in C++Builder for __declspec (align (n))? I do not mean the `#pragma pack ([show] | [push | pop] [, identifier], n)`. I need something for the macro.

I have a problem with adopt a code below (especially for `__declspec(align(n))`):

```
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)

#define LJ_NORET    __declspec(noreturn)
#define LJ_ALIGN(n) __declspec(align(n))
#define LJ_INLINE   __inline
#define LJ_AINLINE  __forceinline
#define LJ_NOINLINE __declspec(noinline)
#if defined(_M_IX86)
#define LJ_FASTCALL __fastcall
#endif

static LJ_AINLINE uint32_t lj_ffs(uint32_t x)
{
  uint32_t r; _BitScanForward(&r, x); return r;
}

static LJ_AINLINE uint32_t lj_fls(uint32_t x)
{
  uint32_t r; _BitScanReverse(&r, x); return r;
}

#define lj_bswap(x) (_byteswap_ulong((x)))

#else
```

Comment: im not sure so i post as a comment ... #pragma align ?

Comment: I need to do a macro by using keywords, rather than pragma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [[align]] attribute is not yet implemented in C++Builder. I'm not sure where this is in the priorities list for C++0x support.

Comment: In that case I have to manually change the following macros "LJ_ALIGN " to "#pragma pack...". Thanks!